# mmap() Allocation Fails With Large Numbers?

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, mmap, errno

On macOS Big-Sur With 32GB of Ram of which 24+ are free I ran the following program:

```
void *void_new_block = mmap(nullptr, sizeof(MyClass) + 300000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1,
                            0);
if (void_new_block == (void *) (-1)) {
    std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}
```

But mmap keeps failing and I see on screen the following message:

```
Invalid argument
```

What's the reason for such strange behaviour?

Plus, `sizeof(MyClass) = 48`

Comment: Tried too on: https://onlinegdb.com/kbXVh8RzR

Comment: Tried too on ubunto 18.04

Comment: I changed to `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` and it worked, why is that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/mmap.2.html `Conforming applications must specify either MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED.`

Comment: You probably should multiply `sizeof(MyClass)` by 300000 instead of adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/mmap.2.html):

> Conforming applications must specify either MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED.

[Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) has a similar restriction:

> This behavior is determined by including exactly one of the following values in flags
>
> MAP_SHARED
>
> MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE
>
> MAP_PRIVATE

Comment: Can you explain more what they mean and why we need them?

Comment: Btw I liked your youtube channel :)

Comment: @pow I've never used them myself, I recommend reading the man pages they're all explained there